# Awesomplete - get selected text

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, autocompletebox

Is there a straightforward way to get the text in an awesomplete field (https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/)?

```
var input = document.getElementById("inputlist");
alert(input.value);
```

shows NaN!

Answer (score 9):

You need to add the event either  awesomplete-select or awesomplete-selectcomplete

*In regular Javascript*

```
var input = document.getElementById("inputlist"); 
new Awesomplete(input, {list: yourlist});
document.getElementById('inputlist').addEventListener('awesomplete-selectcomplete',function(){
  alert(this.value); 
});
```

*In Jquery*

```
var input=$("#inputlist")[0];
new Awesomplete(input, {list: yourlist});
$("#inputlist").on('awesomplete-selectcomplete',function(){
  alert(this.value);
});
```