# Get selected value in autocomplete dropdown

Tags: javascript

I'm using awesomplete plugin to get an autocomplete dropdown. I'm able to get the dropdown working, however I find no straightforward way in accessing the value selected!

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8y8xpqfk/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Auto complete</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/awesomplete.css"/>
    <script src="js/awesomplete.js" async></script>
</head>

<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="awesomplete" list="mylist" onchange="callMe()"/>
            <datalist id="mylist">
                <option>Ada</option>
                <option>Java</option>
                <option>JavaScript</option>
                <option>Brainfuck</option>
                <option>LOLCODE</option>
                <option>Node.js</option>
                <option>Ruby on Rails</option>
            </datalist>
        </td>
</table>

<script>
    var callMe = function () {
        alert("Something selected..");
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The function never gets called, `onchange` is not triggered!

Comment: The `onselect` should be `onchange`.

Comment: Thx for correcting me, it's still the same. I was checking with `onselect` and pasted the same code, updated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've attached the event listener to the `input` event. This event encompasses:

- onchange
- onkeyup
- onpaste (when supported)

```js
var input = document.querySelector(".awesomplete");

input.addEventListener("input", inputHandler);

function inputHandler() {
  alert(this.value)
}
```

```html
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="awesomplete" list="mylist"/>
            <datalist id="mylist">
                <option>Ada</option>
                <option>Java</option>
                <option>JavaScript</option>
                <option>Brainfuck</option>
                <option>LOLCODE</option>
                <option>Node.js</option>
                <option>Ruby on Rails</option>
            </datalist>
        </td>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: while this answer does this job, it just does not work when there's `onchange`, it needs a 'return' or a mouse click. Any insights how can I trigger the function when the value is selected/changed?

Comment: If you change things to this: `input.addEventListener("input", inputHandler);`, you'll see that the alert will fire the moment anything changes (keyboard input, removal of text, selecting from the list, etc.)

Comment: Please look at the adjusted answer and run the updated code to see if this is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The function is called before it is defined. I've changed the jsfiddle load type, then it works. Also be aware of the difference between onselect and onchange. Change will fire after blur of your input and the value has changed.

https://jsfiddle.net/8y8xpqfk/11/

```
var callMe = function (elem) {
    alert("Onchange: "+elem.value);
}

var callMeToo = function (elem) {
    alert("Onselect: "+elem.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine is working. In order to obtain the selected value you have to pass the `event` object to the `callMe` function as argument. Then you could fetch the selected value.

```js
function callMe(event) {
        alert("Something selected.."+event.target.value);
}
```

```html
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="awesomplete" list="mylist" onchange="callMe(event)"/>
            <datalist id="mylist">
                <option>Ada</option>
                <option>Java</option>
                <option>JavaScript</option>
                <option>Brainfuck</option>
                <option>LOLCODE</option>
                <option>Node.js</option>
                <option>Ruby on Rails</option>
            </datalist>
        </td>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: This works wonderfully here when I 'Run code snippet'. If I copy the same to jsfiddle or webstorm, it simply doesn't work!! What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `:selected`, as `datalist` elements can have multiple options, but you can watch the input for change. Here's a jQuery solution:
 `$("input").focusout(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});`

Comment: This doesn't use the change event.

Comment: Nor does it use the onchange event. Question is seeking solution to value selected. Onchange is the event they were using, but I see nothing saying it is required/desired. Am I missing something?

Comment: *onchange* is the HTML attribute and DOM property name (aka [*event handler* name](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handlers)), the event type is *change*, per the [*WHATWG living standard*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-change). *cf.* `element.addEventListener('change', ...)`. While the OP used "onselect", there was also: "*… onchange is not triggered*" so it seems the change event was intended (or not…).

Comment: "it seems" is relative and you can't quantify. it looks to me like they wanted a solution. "(or not...)" or not what? Does it or does it not seem? I'm confused by this entire back and forth, but that is the oddest. I dont get this (again), but at least if you disagreed, ok you were standing for something. but now, meh, or not. you do agree? Carry on.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use the onchange or onselect .Awesomplete has events such as awesomplete-select and awesomplete-selectcomplete.
Check this link for similar question.
[Awesomplete - get selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35864545/awesomplete-get-selected-text/38074216#38074216)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="awesomplete.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="awesomplete.css">  
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="awesomplete" list="mylist" id="someid" />
            <datalist id="mylist">
                <option>Ada</option>
                <option>Java</option>
                <option>JavaScript</option>
                <option>Brainfuck</option>
                <option>LOLCODE</option>
                <option>Node.js</option>
                <option>Ruby on Rails</option>
            </datalist>
        </td>
        </tr>
</table>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('someid').addEventListener('awesomplete-selectcomplete',function(){
alert(this.value);
});
</script>
</html>
```